# Scroll layout in web view android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have this web view on which I have a text box at the bottom. The
problem is when I click on this text box the keypad pops up and covers
it. How can I scroll the web view so that the text box remain above the
keypad. In i phone it is handled automatically.

Comment: Try adding this to the Activity in question in the manifest: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"`.

Comment: i have changed this in manifest file then still same problem.

Comment: Can you post the layout xml file code here. I think it can be resolved by changes in xml only.

Comment: Make the `WebView` scrollable, this is one of the things to do too.

Comment: I have already set scroll view in webview.xml layout.

Comment: You set the `WebView` to be scrollable from the XML ? Or you did like so? :`wView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); 
wView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);` ?

Comment: i tried to add scrollview in xml layout and tried by adding setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); in activity file but not getting appropriate result.

Comment: So, to sum the things up: 1. You have set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"` for the corresponding Activity in the manifest? (please paste it here, if not a problem) 2. You have set `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true)` to the `WebView` programmatically too? and after al lthis the soft keyboard (not the hardware one) is still overlapping the `WebView` ?

Comment: <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"/> .and see also this webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN|View.FOCUS_UP);
  webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

Comment: Ok, one last try I saw here: "http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html" is to set the Activity to `stateVisible` (instead of `stateHidden`.

Comment: G00dy , you have given Link saws "Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist. "

Comment: It's a problem of pasting it (remove the " symbol at the end of the address) `http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html`.

Comment: Not resolved our problem by changing stateVisible instead of stateHidden in manifest file.

Comment: Ok, now without the code, we're only guessing the obvious. Paste it (the Activity, the Manifest etc. so we can assess).

Comment: I am not able to post code because of below reputation.what should i do?

Comment: You're not able to EDIT your original question?

Comment: webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.m_webview);
  
  webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(15);
  webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
  webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN|View.FOCUS_UP);
  webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
  
  webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this, appManager.getDBManager()), "Android");
  
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i came out from this stuck..

I just added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in my maniefest file inside wab activity declaration class.

And Added below in style.xml file:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this property in your activity**

```
<activity
            android:name="YourActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

Comment: I changed your suggestion in my manifest file,but still same problem i am facing.